# Edge WebRTC joined mediastream displaying old frames

Tags: webrtc, microsoft-edge

https://cryptsy.tv/#!/test

(To broadcast, click join channel then broadcast)
(To join a broadcast just click join channel)

Whenever using the above example on edge it glitches and shows old frames during playback, causing it to appear as if the person is teleporting around the screen. Is this behavior being observed with everyone else? I am using two rtc connections sending audio and video seperately then joining them using a mediastream.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/19298399/

Comment: I am not able to make a test with your example in the link. page does not playing video. I suggest you to create a working example and post it here. We will again try to make a test with it to produce the issue.

Comment: https://cryptsy.tv/assets/angular-views/test.html

is a working example now. Open two windows. Click broadcast on one and watch on the other!